# MySQL: How to reference on two columns on the same table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table with 3 columns 'Player1', 'Player2' and 'Winner'. I want the 'Winner' column to reference either the 'Player1' or the 'Player2' column. Nothing else should be inserted than an entry of 'Player1' or 'Player2'. I tried it with

```
ALTER TABLE GAMES 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_winner FOREIGN KEY (WINNER) REFERENCES GAMES (PLAYER1, PLAYER2);
```

but i got an error.

Comment: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'mydatabase.#sql-c4_4d' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't create a foreign key like that.  If you wanted to enforce this in the database, you would need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE GAMES
ADD CHECK (WINNER = PLAYER1 OR WINNER = PLAYER2);
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html 

"The CHECK  clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines"

Comment: The best I can suggest is a trigger then. I didn't realize MySql ignored them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a second table PLAYERS that has all unique players.  Then in GAMES you could just index into that table with Player1 and Player2.  all 3 columns in winner could then have a foreign key constraint that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

The number of referencing and referenced columns do not match. You can of course refer two columns in a table. But refer two columns with two columns.